# Add a link to the notification about the "Create new tags" privilege

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, profile-page, notifications

> [image: You have earned new privilege message]

It might be helpful, if this notification showed some information or came with a link to more information.

I am sure, I can find the information somewhere but just being able to click might make it (even) easier for people to make themselves useful.

What (also) might be helpful information here:

1. a list of all tags
2. a list of tags I have been active in
3. a list of tags where I have been active in with no description
4. a list of requested tags (if this exists in the area of or near my expertise)
5. guidelines for creating tags and editing tag descriptions

---

Update: The [suggested link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) in the comment takes care of point 5.

Comment: Linking to this page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags would be enough, if not the simplest thing that might work, right?

Comment: @rene agreed. Most of the information is there.

Comment: Awesome! I support this feature request.

Answer (score 7):

I see your request and raise you: This is now in place for for **all** new privileges. In each one of the "congrats on the new privilege" callouts the name of the privilege now links to the relevant help center article.

Comment: wow, quick resolution! Thank you.